# Suppose $n$ is a positive integer. Decide the remainder of $x^{2n}-x^{n}$ when divided by $2$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

So, I tried solving this problem in the following way (though I think I'm begging the question...)

The possible remainders of $x^{2n}-x^{n}$ when divided by $2$ is $0$ and $1$. We wish to solve the following congruence $x^{2n}-x^{n}\equiv b\pmod 2$, where $b=0$ or $b=1$.

Now, Suppose $b=0$ (this is where I think I'm begging the question!). Then $x^{2n}-x^{n}\equiv 0\pmod 2 \Leftrightarrow 2\vert (x^{2n}-x^{n}-0) \Leftrightarrow x^{2n}\equiv (x^{n})^{2}\equiv x^{n}\pmod 2$. If we let $a=x^{n}$. Then it is clear that $(x^{n})^{2}\equiv x^{n}\pmod 2 \Leftrightarrow a^{2}\equiv a\pmod 2$ and by Fermat's little theorem we know that $a^{2}\equiv a\pmod 2$ is true. Thus $x^{2n}-x^{n}$ has a remainder of $0$ when divided by $2$.

Is this correct? Or am I just begging the question?

Comment: I like your usage of "begging the question"

Comment: Are you being sarcastic or what are you actually saying? Haha.

Comment: I was being serious.  Many people speak of [begging the question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Begging_the_question) when they mean raising the question, but that's not what it means in classical logic

Comment: okay. Nice to hear that I'm accurately using concepts in classical logic.

Answer (score 2):

You are overthinking it; just note that

- for a fixed $x$, any power of it has the same parity as $x$
- the difference of two numbers of the same parity is even

Thus, immediately, we see that the remainder is always $0$.

Comment: Yeah. Sometimes I think some of my math books are structured in a way that makes me overthink exercises...Though I have to say that it is not obvious to me that every power of $x$ has the same parity as $x$. But given that this is true, the solution becomes very simple and elegant. But is my solution valid?

Comment: @VictorGaleano I'd say yes.

Comment: How would you go about showing that all powers of $x$ has the same parity as $x$? I figured it was pretty easy when $x$ is even, but when $x$ is odd it seems more difficult. Suppose $x$ is even. Then $x=2m$ for some $m\in \mathbb{Z}$. So, $x^{n}=(2m)^{n}=2^{n}\cdot m^{n}$. And since $2\vert 2^{n}$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ we get that $2\vert (2m)^{n}$. Thus $x^{n}$ has the same parity as $x$ when $x$ is even.

Comment: @VictorGaleano $E×E=E$; $O×O=O$. Anyway this is closed as duplicate so won't proceed further.

Comment: Alright. Thanks anyway

Comment: @VictorGaleano Accept my answer!

Answer (score 1):

As you said, $x\equiv0$ or $1\pmod2$.

You wish to find $x^{2n}-x^n\pmod2$.

If $x\equiv0\pmod2$, what is $x^n\pmod2$?  $x^{2n}\pmod2$?   $x^{2n}-x^n\pmod2$?

If $x\equiv1\pmod2$, what is $x^n\pmod2$?  $x^{2n}\pmod2$?  $x^{2n}-x^n\pmod2$?

Comment: It is correct that by Fermat's little theorem $a^2\equiv a$ so $x^{2n}\equiv x^n\pmod 2$ for all integers $a$ and $x$ (perhaps that is a more succinct way of putting the argument you were trying to make)

Comment: Case 1: If $x\equiv 0\pmod 2$. Then $x^{n}\equiv 0^{n}\equiv 0\pmod 2$ and $x^{2n}\equiv 0^{2n}\equiv 0\pmod 2$. So $x^{2n}-x^{n}\equiv 0-0\equiv 0\pmod 2$.

Case 2: If $x\equiv 1\pmod 2$. Then $x^{n}\equiv 1^{n}\equiv 1\pmod 2$ and $x^{2n}\equiv 1^{2n}\equiv 1\pmod 2$. So $x^{2n}-x^{n}\equiv 1-1\equiv 0\pmod 2$. Thus $x^{2n}-x^{n}\equiv 0\pmod 2$?

Comment: You got it, @VictorGaleano;  so in either case $x^{2n}-x^n\equiv0\pmod 2$

Comment: cool! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{2n}-x^n=x^n(x^n-1)\equiv0\pmod2$.